# Trying to access class passed back via JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I am calling this function via a JSON object

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult GetMatchDetails(int id)
    {
        var match = GetRepository<Match>().Get(id);

        return Json(match, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

where the var match is from the class (trimed down version but im not needing to use the rest)

```
 public class Match : Entity
 {
    public virtual DateTime? MatchDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Boxer> Boxers { get; set; }
    public virtual string Location { get; set; }
    public virtual MatchResult Result { get; set; }
    public virtual int Rounds { get; set; }
 }
```

and the call from the javascript is (from the function called)

```
        var matchStuff = null;
        //Get a class which will have the Match and two boxers part of it
        $.getJSON("/BoxingPredictionLeague/GetMatchDetails/" + MatchId, function(data){
            matchStuff = data;
            alert(matchStuff.Id);

        });
```

Where the alert is I have tried to alert out the Id using matchStuff[0].Id as well as matchStuff.Id but it doesnt alert at all... seems to just be crashing or that object is null!

Comment: Suggestion to help in debugging it: Install Firebug into Firefox, start it up, and watch the Console tab when you cause that JSON call to execute. I'm not certain, but I think it should show up in there with more detailed information on what happened than VS's Debugger will provide.

Comment: mmm ive tried to put breakpoints in the javascript in both chrome and firebug and it doesn't get hit for some reason. But the code after it does get hit. As i have other code that continues while the JSON object is waiting for its data back... could it be something to do with that?

Answer (score 1):

**Obvious questions:**

Are you sure you're getting an object returned from your repository?

Are you sure there's a 'Id' property? (its not listed in the code sample)

**Otherwise:**

If you use chrome, you can do the following to see exactly what is being returned via Json.

1. Goto Tools -> Developer Tools
2. Click on 'Resources'
3. Underneath those buttons there's a little bar, click on XHR.
4. On the left you'll see all the ajax calls the page initiated. Headers will show what you're sending; content will show what you've received. The content is straight JSON, but you should be able to determine it from there.

If you're using firebug:

1. Open firebug via the icon on the bottom left (ensure its enabled)
2. Click on the 'Net' tab
3. Underneath those buttons there's a little bar, click on XHR.
4. You'll see a list of all ajax calls. expanding one will enable you to see both the headers and the content response.

One of these two methods should help you track it down --otherwise everything else looks correct via your code sample.

Comment: mmm seems my dad isn't coming back to my json object... do i need to do anything with my class before i Pass it back? does it need to be a ICollection or something?

Comment: You should be able to just pass the object as-is using Json(...). What does your XHR content show as being returned? My other thought is the `virtual` keyword may be throwing off the JSON function. Is there a reason you need those on your object properties?